# tkinter program GUI behaviour - opens two windows instead of one, labels not updated

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following program which is used to create a very basic GUI:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import test

class main_fun():
    def init_proc(self):
        stLabelStatus['text']="Started executing the test...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procA(self):
        print "inside ProcA...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcA...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procB(self):
        print "inside ProcB...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcB...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procC(self):
        print "inside ProcC...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcC...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procD(self):
        print "inside ProcD...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcD...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procE(self):
        print "inside ProcE...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcE...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def procF(self):
        print "inside ProcF...."
        stLabelStatus['text'] = "Running ProcF...."
        time.sleep(5)

    def main_control(self):
        stLabelStatus.config(text='Running Tests....')
        self.init_proc()
        self.procA()
        self.procB()
        self.procC()
        self.procD()
        self.procE()
        self.procF()

tests=main_fun()

stGUI = Tk()
stGUI.geometry("450x300+50+50")
stGUI.resizable(0,0)
stGUI.title("Testing GUI")

arial12 = tkFont.Font(root = stGUI, family='Arial', size=12, weight='bold')
arial16 = tkFont.Font(root = stGUI, family='Arial', size=16, weight='bold')

stLabelTestNumlbl = Label(stGUI,text="Test No.")
stLabelTestNumlbl['font'] = arial12
stLabelTestNumlbl.place(x=120,y=40)

stInputTestNum = Entry(stGUI, width=6)
stInputTestNum['font'] = arial12
stInputTestNum.place(x=250,y=40)

stLabelStatuslbl = Label(stGUI,text="Status")
stLabelStatuslbl['font'] = arial12
# stLabelStatus.pack()
# stLabelStatus.grid(row=0,column=0)
stLabelStatuslbl.place(x=20,y=180)

stLabelResultlbl = Label(stGUI,text="Result")
stLabelResultlbl['font'] = arial12
stLabelResultlbl.place(x=20,y=240)

stButtonStart = Button(stGUI,text="Start", command=tests.main_control)
stButtonStart['font'] = arial16
stButtonStart.place(x=180,y=110)

stLabelStatus = Label(stGUI, text="", anchor=CENTER)
stLabelResult = Label(stGUI, text="", anchor=CENTER)
stLabelStatus.place(x=90,y=183)
stLabelResult.place(x=90,y=243)

stGUI.mainloop()
```

Even though the GUI was created, I have a couple of issues here:

1. there is a small window titled `tk` that opens up along with my window titled `Testing GUI` (See the image below). I remember it was not there when I started out, looks like something that I recently added created it. I can't really understand exactly what though. How can I remove that tiny pest window or at least hide it?

[image: Windows]

2. I'm unable to update the Status label at runtime even though I've inserted `stLabelStatus['text']="Running ProcA...."` and similar statements as required in the flow. All that I can see is the very last line in the flow (`procF` is the last called function) `stLabelStatus['text']="Running ProcF...."`.

How can I update the status during runtime as per my requirement? I'm sure its possible and some logical mistake I'm doing.

Comment: 1. "I remember it was not there" - what stops you from finding the cause by going back and testing? 2. does the function excute at all? check the reference in `command=` - is that supposed to be like that?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted does not run, and will not create two windows if we comment out the non-code portions. Also, unless the fonts contribute to the problem, they  aren't necessary in the example.

Comment: @handle, I meant when I started out with just the window layout and the placement of the controls/widgets, only the window titled `Testing GUI` was there. The `tk` window appeared after I added `command=` to the button.

Comment: This confirms what I wrote: the question is what is wrong with `command`, isn't it? Show some effort.

Comment: @handle, I too understand that. But what I don't understand is how will that make a separate window. I created an object, made an instance of it and called a function in `command=`. This is fairly straight and doesn't look wrong to me (I'm a total noob in tkinter) as far as my limited knowledge is concerned.

Comment: I only get one window when I run your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the above changes I did make the program executable now and show the exact same problems I'm still facing.

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help. The code you posted, when run through a python interpreter, does not create two windows.

Comment: That's wierd. How about issue no 2? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Your code example is getting _more_ complex! See the 2nd comment. And have another look at the working code I posted as answer, ie. the parentheses, or rather, the lack thereof.

Comment: It does not give an error, but is it valid syntax? Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

Comment: (sorry) Yes, inheritance argument list is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed that command refers correctly to the `tests` object (of your custom class).

But this

```
#!python3

from tkinter import *

class main_fun():
    def main_c():
        print("main_c")
        print(stLabelStatus)
        stLabelStatus['text']="Status updated...."

tests=main_fun()

stGUI = Tk()
stGUI.geometry("450x300+50+50")
stGUI.resizable(0,0)
stGUI.title("Testing GUI")

stButtonStart = Button(stGUI,text="Start", command=tests.main_c)
stButtonStart.place(x=180,y=100)

stLabelStatus = Label(stGUI, text="", anchor=CENTER)
stLabelStatus.place(x=90,y=183)

stGUI.mainloop()
```

gives this output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: main_c() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

which states an exact problem and probably would yield the answer in web search results.

But taking the hint at arguments, one will notice the class definition and its only method. You'd look at the [Python documentation or tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) and notice that you're doing it wrong:

`class` does not have parameters, but the method must have at least one (`self`):

```
class main_fun:
    def main_c(self):
        print("main_c")
        print(stLabelStatus)
        stLabelStatus['text']="Status updated...."
```

Success!

---

Tested with a fresh Python 2.7.13:

```
#!python2
#coding=utf-8
from Tkinter import *

def my_method():
    stLabelStatus['text']="Status updated...."

stGUI = Tk()

stButtonStart = Button(
    stGUI,
    text="Start",
    command=my_method
    )
stButtonStart.place(x=0, y=0)

stLabelStatus = Label(stGUI)
stLabelStatus.place(x=0, y=30)

stGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've updated the program which can be executed. I still face the same issues.